# AJAX div data loads doesn't update after initial load in Chrome, but does in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This is a bizarre problem - I have a very simple app that makes an AJAX call to a flask endpoint every 15 seconds and returns a number, which changes pretty frequently (inbox count).  Then it's just a jquery selector to update the div with this data.

When I first put this thing together a few months ago there was no issues, I kind of forgot about it until recently when I made a few small changes.  Now for some reason the page will load initially with the correct count, but when the AJAX call is made, it doesn't update in Chrome, but does in Safari (haven't tested other browsers yet).  It use to work fine in both.  I'm pretty confident this has nothing to do with the change I made as it was pretty trivial and it certainly wouldn't only impact one browser.

I can see the call being made to the endpoint in the network section of dev tools for both browsers, and it is returning the data is it should, it's just that the data never changes in Chrome.  It's as if chrome is caching that value or something, so it does the AJAX call but ignores the new value and just uses what it had several iterations ago.

If i hit the AJAX endpoint directly in the browser, it works as it should.  Its only the AJAX call within Chrome that keeps the "stale" data.

Any ideas what would cause this?

EDIT: Code Below

```
function outer(){
    var play_count=0
    function updateRefunds() {
        $.getJSON('/countdown', function (data) {
            if(data.refunds==0){
                $('#canvas').show()
                $('#refunds').hide()
                if (play_count==0){
                    $('#katy')[0].play()
                    play_count++
                }
            }
            $('#refunds').text(data.refunds);
        });
    }
    return updateRefunds
}
var savestate=outer()
setInterval('savestate()', 15000);//every 15 sec
```

Comment: Could you provide you js code that update the page?

Comment: If it's a GET request, the browser could be caching the response -- but hard to tell without any code to look at.

Comment: i know it's annoying without the code, it's just there is a lot to get the whole picture.  I'll show the JS code, but I can't really put the python, JS, html, CSS, etc... it'd be a novel.

Comment: Replace `'savestate()'` with  setInterval(savestate, 15000).

Comment: @Matt.k I don't think that matters actually.  It may not be the best practices way of doing it, but the string will be eval'd at run time.  The problem was that the browser was caching it.  I fixed that by appending a timestamp as a query parameter.